How do i resolve WinError3 No file found
so i'm an absolute beginner in python and i have a script that checks the function of certain genus of bacteria and gives me the output in an excel file. I have tried to debug thr script and it keeps saying that the File or Directory doesn't exist. I have included the code below if it helps.
import os
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from Bio import Entrez
from time import sleep


# Set your email here (required by NCBI)
Entrez.email = "ronnyghosh007@gmail.com"

def search_ncbi_for_functions(genus_name):
    search_term = f"{genus_name}[Organism]"
    
    try:
        handle = Entrez.esearch(db="taxonomy", term=search_term)
        record = Entrez.read(handle)
        handle.close()

        if record["IdList"]:
            tax_id = record["IdList"][0]  # Take the first result
            
            handle = Entrez.efetch(db="taxonomy", id=tax_id, retmode="xml")
            tax_data = Entrez.read(handle)
            handle.close()
            
            lineage = tax_data[0].get('Lineage', 'Unknown')
            scientific_name = tax_data[0].get('ScientificName', 'Unknown')
            function = tax_data[0].get('OtherNames', 'Function Not Available')
            return scientific_name, lineage, function
        else:
            return genus_name, "No Data Found", "No Function Available"
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching data for {genus_name}: {e}")
        return genus_name, "Error", "Error"

def read_genus_from_excel(file_path):
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
        if 'Genus' in df.columns:
            return df['Genus'].tolist()
        else:
            raise ValueError("The Excel file must contain a 'Genus' column.")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Error: File '{file_path}' not found.")
        return []
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while reading the Excel file: {e}")
        return []


def main(input_excel, output_excel):
    # Get the directory for the output file
    output_dir = os.path.dirname(output_excel)
    
    # Create the directory if it doesn't exist
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
    
    # Check if input and output files exist
    if not os.path.exists(input_excel):
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"Input file not found: {input_excel}")
    
    print(f"Output directory created: {output_dir}")


    genus_list = read_genus_from_excel("/Users/ronny/Desktop/Potato/KE.xlsx")
    
    results = []
    
    for genus in genus_list:
        print(f"Searching NCBI for genus: {genus}")
        scientific_name, lineage, function = search_ncbi_for_functions(genus)
        results.append([scientific_name, lineage, function])
        
        sleep(3)
    
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=["Genus", "Lineage", "Function"])
    result_df.to_excel(output_excel, index=False)
    print(f"Results saved to {output_excel}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_file = "KE.xlsx"
    output_file = "genus_functions.xlsx"
    
    try:
        main(input_file, output_file)
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(f"File not found: {e}")
    except PermissionError as e:
        print(f"Permission denied: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")

Any help is appreciated cause i have absolutly no idea what i'm doing wrong
I have tried to create a new virtual environment and tried to debug the code line by line. I have also tried to run it on WSL on VS code and check if it works there. On WSl it gives me the error File not found: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''. i don't know what to do after this.
I thought it was a missing file but I have checked and all the files are there Picture of Files

This definitely isn't the shortest code necessary. I also suspect that the error is exactly the problem: file not found. That's not a programming problem, that's just a missing file (or wrong file name).

Yeah, I figured I was missing the file but I checked quite thoroughly, the files do exist

Why did you tag [tag:PowerShell]?

os.path.dirname(output_excel) returns the directory component of a pathname, i.e. an empty string if output_excel is defined as "genus_functions.xlsx" (no directory component here). Hence, os.makedirs('') fails with No such file or directory: ''…

Don't make us guess where the error happened.  Please post the full error traceback message.
